# Inception5h vs Inception V4, what is 5h

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, protocol-buffers, models, tensorboard

I have been following github repository for "**Tensorflow on Android**".

This [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/slim), shows all the inception models but not inception5h. 
The demo application for tensorflow on github uses inception5h, as shown [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/WORKSPACE)

```
   new_http_archive(
      name = "inception5h",
      build_file = "models.BUILD",
      url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/models/inception5h.zip",
      sha256 = "d13569f6a98159de37e92e9c8ec4dae8f674fbf475f69fe6199b514f756d4364"
    )
```

**Please explain**

1.Why it is ***inception5h*** and not ***inceptionV5***?

2.Why is ***inception5h*** not listed in the models link above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inception 5h is equivalent to Inception V1. This just comes down to a bit of confusion of what versioning scheme we were publishing things under :)

Comment: I [retrained](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py) and [optimized for inception](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/optimize_for_inference.py) the inception V3. The retrained APK works with inference time 1200~2000ms and with inception5H model, the APK works at 200~400ms. Is it possible to attain similar inference time on my retrained APK, with inceptionV3?

Comment: Andrew Harp 
thanks for the information about InceptionV5. I have tried retraining/finetune the [inceptionV1](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/slim/scripts/finetune_inception_v1_on_flowers.sh) slim model and am facing [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43647446/no-operation-named-input-in-the-graph-error-while-fine-tuning-retraining-ince) please help me out.