# No Operation named [input] in the Graph" error while fine tuning/retraining inceptionV1 slim model

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, protocol-buffers, models

I am trying to finetune/retrain InceptionV1 model here, on my own data. I was able to

1. Convert the Image data to TFR format data using [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/slim/datasets/download_and_convert_flowers.py).
2. Pass the converted data to ***[finetune_inception_v1_on_flowers](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/slim/scripts/finetune_inception_v1_on_flowers.sh)***
3. Complete the training and evaluation in according to the script file above, I am attaching the logs here.

   ```
   INFO:tensorflow:global step 1000: loss = 0.1833 (20.37 sec/step) INFO:tensorflow:Stopping Training. 
   INFO:tensorflow:Finished training! Saving model to disk. INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer. 
   WARNING:tensorflow:From eval_image_classifier.py:157: streaming_recall_at_k (from tensorflow.contrib.metrics.python.ops.metric_ops) is deprecated and will be removed after 2016-11-08. Instructions for updating: Please use streaming_sparse_recall_at_k, and reshape labels from [batch_size] to [batch_size, 1]. 
       INFO:tensorflow:Evaluating /tmp/flowers-models/inception_v1/all/model.ckpt-1000 
       INFO:tensorflow:Starting evaluation at 2017-04-26-14:59:28 INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from /tmp/flowers-models/inception_v1/all/model.ckpt-1000 
       INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [1/4] 
       INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [2/4] 
       INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [3/4] 
       INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [4/4] 
       2017-04-26 20:30:23.505265: I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] eval/Recall_5[1] 
       2017-04-26 20:30:23.505420: I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] eval/Accuracy[1] 
       INFO:tensorflow:Finished evaluation at 2017-04-26-15:00:23
   ```

4.The training process genertaed many checkpoints, two graph.pbtxt files. I used the latest checkpoint and the graph.pbtxt file in the freeze tool and generated a .pb file, according to the discussion [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4766#issuecomment-297077669), I used following parameters

> --input_graph=/../../graph.pbtxt
>
> --output_node_names=InceptionV1/Logits/Predictions/Softmax

5. Now I am trying to use the .pb file in tensorflow demo application, by making few changes toClassifierActivity.java in tensorflow demo android app and it shows an error to me,

> **No Operation named [input] in the Graph**"

following are the changes I made toClassifierActivity.java

> private static final int INPUT_SIZE = 224;//224//299
>
> private static final int IMAGE_MEAN = 117;//117//128
>
> private static final float IMAGE_STD = 1;//1//128
>
> private static final String INPUT_NAME ="input";//input
>
> private static final String OUTPUT_NAME ="InceptionV1/Logits/Predictions/Softmax";//output
>
> private static final String MODEL_FILE ="file:///android_asset/frozen_1000_graph.pb";//tensorflow_inception_graph
>
> private static final String LABEL_FILE ="file:///android_asset/labels.txt";//imagenet_comp_graph_label_strings

6. As suggested in discussion link above, I tried Summarize graph tool on my frozen_1000_graph.pb and got the following output.

> No inputs spotted. No variables spotted. Found 1 possible outputs:
>   (name=InceptionV1/Logits/Predictions/Softmax, op=Softmax) Found
>   5598451 (5.60M) const parameters, 0 (0) variable parameters, and 114
>   control_edges Op types used: 472 Const, 230 Mul, 173 Add, 172 Sub, 116
>   Identity, 114 Sum, 58 Reshape, 58 Conv2D, 57 Rsqrt, 57 Relu, 57
>   Reciprocal, 57 Square, 57 SquaredDifference, 57 Mean, 57 StopGradient,
>   13 MaxPool, 9 ConcatV2, 1 Squeeze, 1 RandomUniform, 1 Softmax, 1
>   RealDiv, 1 QueueDequeueV2, 1 Floor, 1 FIFOQueueV2, 1 BiasAdd, 1
>   AvgPool.

**Please help me understand, how I can fix this issue**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/train_image_classifier.py#L454) are the input to the network created, so if you can add 
images = tf.identity(images, name='Inputs') to name the tensor to the network.

Comment: the link is broken

Comment: Fixed broken link

Comment: @SergioGuadarrama, i didn't understand how to named the network. I'm using tensorflow for react-native and i get the same error, but i don't know how to fix it.