# Refering to issue --->No Operation named [input] in the Graph" error while fine tuning/retraining inceptionV1 slim model

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, protocol-buffers, models

This question is in reference to http://stackoverflow.com/a/43662693/4571192.

I am also facing the same issue,but was not able to understand the solution pointed out.
where should this be added:images = tf.identity(images, name='Inputs')
And how does impact the network and how is it linked to the previously retrained network.

Kindly help in resolving this error.

i did not add any comment there due to low reputation points.

Comment: Can you quote the most relevant parts of the linked question and answer into your own, for clarity?

Comment: In the question ,as the solution states-"Hereare the input to the network created, so if you can add images = tf.identity(images, name='Inputs') to name the tensor to the network" its very unclear on where to add the code: images=tf.identity(images,name='Inputs').  how is it resolving the issue and what was the cause of  it?